# awk to vlookup and print

Tags: awk, programming

I got a comma-separated file

```
# cat data

smartplayer,2222,off
smartplayer,1111,on
scorer,0000,
```

I want to search for smartplayer in $1, get its state from $3
and print like this

```
off-smart-player 2222
on-smart-player 1111
scorer 0000
```

I run this command but it's printing like this

```
# awk '{ if ($1 == smartplayer ) {print $3"-smart-player", $2}}'  data

-smart-player 
-smart-player
```

Comment: BTW, you don't do vlookup operation here

Comment: The script you posted in your question would not produce the output you say it does from the input you posted. In fact it wouldn't produce any output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You needed to specify the field separator:

```
awk -F, '$1=="smartplayer"{ print $3"-smart-player", $2; next }
                          { $1=$1; print }' data
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk -F, '$1=="smartplayer"{$1=$3"-smart-player"} {print $1, $2}' data
off-smart-player 2222
on-smart-player 1111
scorer 0000
```